# What is PEP8 convention to docstring a Class that inherits another class?

Tags: python, pep8, docstring

When I try to follow PEP8 and doc string a class that involves inheritance, PyCharm/PyCode Check for PEP8 always gives me a warning that the inherited parameters have no reference. Is it better to just delete these? Should I mention the params at all in the class that subclasses?

For example

## MODULE 1

```
class Parent:
    """Parent class
    :param plugin: a plugin
    :type plugin: plugin type

    """

    def __init___(self,plugin):
         self.plugin = plugin
```

## MODULE 2

```
class Child(Parent):
    """
    :param plugin: the plugin from parent class
    """
```

Module 2 will give me a warning about plugin having no reference. Best practice for PEP8?

Comment: Personally, I like to have an `__init__(plugin)` in the child, even if all it contains is `super().__init__(plugin)`, so that the signature is clear to the reader (especially if the class definitions are in separate files). That would also satisfy PyCharm's checker. However, remember that what matters is readability/cleanliness of the code, not whether the checker runs without warnings. After all, it is meant to _assist_ you as a developer.

Comment: I do not believe Pep8 has any specific word on this matter, but I believe it is standard practice to not include or mention the doc-string of the parent in the child but rather mention any *child-specific* behavior - the child *inherits* the parent's doc string unless otherwise stated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No canonical PEP8 answer for this, so closing.
Standard practice is to not include or mention the doc string of parent in the child.